# What happens if I unlink my Google account?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm unhappy with the username I picked, and thus far I've only just caught my first Pokemon. I'd love to reset my account, but I'm afraid if I go to my Google settings and unlink my Pokemon go account, I'll be unable to create a new account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm almost if you un-link your account you can't make another username for good on that google account, but I do know that if you go somewhere on the help forums in the app you will get a better description than I just explained. I would tell you what it says on the page directly, but the servers are down again :( I believe the help is right under the settings button, and then you can find the page. I just tried looking on the official support site, but I didn't find anything there, so I'm afraid you have to sign in with another account and find help on the app. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, this is what worries me. I really want to change my account, but I don't think they'll accept a username change.

Comment: What about just creating a new Google account?

Comment: I think If you just use or create another email you should be good to go, but your Pokemon won't carry over :(

Comment: I only have my starter, but I really don't want to lose this login.